# Button fade-in in tabbed application

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have ActionBar Tabs in my application.

I have buttons in the second and third tab that I want to apply a fade-in effect for when the user switches to that tab ( fragment ) .

I am not sure where or how this must be done. I assume not in the onCreate method.
I get a null pointer exception when I try it there ( apparently the components have not been instantiated yet. )

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    int selectedNavigationIndex = (savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getInt("selectedNavigationIndex") : 0);

    InfoFragment infoFragment = new InfoFragment();
    ProductFragment productFragment = new ProductFragment();
    PesticideFragment pesticideFragment = new PesticideFragment();
    SeedFragment seedFragment = new SeedFragment();

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    ActionBar.Tab infoTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("INFORMATION");
    ActionBar.Tab productTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("PRODUCT");
    ActionBar.Tab pesticideTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("PESTICIDE");
    ActionBar.Tab seedTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("SEED");

    infoTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(infoFragment));
    productTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(productFragment));
    pesticideTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(pesticideFragment));
    seedTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(seedFragment));

    actionBar.addTab(infoTab, 0, false);
    actionBar.addTab(productTab, 1, false);
    actionBar.addTab(pesticideTab, 2, false);
    actionBar.addTab(seedTab, 3, false);

    if (selectedNavigationIndex != -1)
    {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(selectedNavigationIndex);
    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to achieve.

```
    Button btn_scanProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ProductTracer);
    animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);

    btn_scanProduct.startAnimation(animFadein);
```

main.xml

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

InfoFragment.java

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {
    ViewGroup rootView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
        AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f , 1.0f ) ; 
        Button btn_scanProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ProductTracer);
        btn_scanProduct.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        fadeIn.setDuration(500);
        fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, findViewById returns null... Does this have anything to do with the fact that my app is defined as singleTask?

Comment: Not sure if singleTask makes a difference. Can you post your main xml so I can see what you are referencing?

Comment: Also, where are you trying to findViewById(R.id.ProductTracer)? Is it in the onCreate method?

Comment: Updated my question with main.xml and InfoFragment.java. Yes, it is in the onCreate method.

Comment: main.xml holds a FrameLayout that works as a fragment container. The first fragment that is loaded is InfoFragment, which returns info.xml which is where the button is.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are referencing the button in the InfoFragment, which might be causing the findViewById to return null. I edited my answer. See if that does anything.

Comment: It doesn't work. I also tried the same but onActivityCreated() which is called after onCreateView. Could this be because I need to reference my main activity to find the view? `Button btn_scanProduct = (Button) ((ProductTracer) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.ProductTracer);`

Comment: What does your info.xml look like?

Comment: Thanks. That last comment made me find the error. I was referencing the wrong button in info.xml. I guess it's time to sleep.